# What formats are accepted in VSTS logging commands?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

When using the logging commands ([documentation here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)), there are many string-only properties, but there are also several GUID and time properties especially for the `task.logdetail` command.

What format are these properties supposed to be when written to the output? i.e. Should GUIDs be included in "N" (no hyphens) or "D" (hyphens), and should time values include dates?

Comment: Better raise a issue on GitHub ? It will get responded fast there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the value of GUID.

》》**should time values include dates?**

Both datetime include time value are working fine, for example: 2016/11/28; 2016/11/28 3:00:05; 11/28/2016; 11/28/2016 4:00:10

Simple code:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logdetail id=a804d160-f69f-4e8a-bdd2-0076d716a01f;name=project1;type=build;order=1;starttime=2016/11/27]create new timeline record"

Write-Host "##vso[task.logdetail id=a804d160-f69f-4e8a-bdd2-0076d716a01f;progress=100;state= Completed;finishtime=2016/11/29]update"
```

Result
[image]